# What are Nidhogg's actual controls?

Tags: nidhogg

Nidhogg's control assignment screen and "how to play" menu option are rather... uninformative. Sure, I can move and jump and attack, but the controls clearly do far more than is immediately apparent; for instance, holding up and pressing attack will throw your sword. There also seems to be some condition under which you can disarm your opponent (or be disarmed yourself), but I have no idea when that happens.

So what are Nidhogg's **actual** controls? What sorts of moves can I do under which circumstances by entering in a series of inputs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go, I searched around for the same thing earlier so I thought I'd share.
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=216329928#213850

> You may change your key configuration by clicking the button at the at
>   the bottom-right of the screen at the Start menu. Alternatively, you
>   may find the button in "How to Play". You may have to move a bit
>   before the button appears.
>
> These controls are actually for two players using the same keyboard.
>   But I'll list what I found most optimal for single player.
>
> **Controls**
>   Lateral Movement: Left and Right
>   Duck: Down | S
>   Jump: G (I recommend changing this to Space)
>   Roll: Down while moving
>   Crawl: Move left or right while ducking
>   Get Up: Left or Right while knocked down
>   Raise Sabre: Up | W
>   Lower Sabre: Down | S
>   Pick Up Sabre: Down | S
>   Lunge: F
>   Prepare Sabre for Throwing: Hold Up or W beyond the highest sabre position
>   Throw Sabre: F while sabre is held aloft
>   Instantly Throw Sabre: Up and F simultaneously
>   Dive-Kick: F while in the air
>   Trip: F while crouched
>   Punch: F while disarmed
>   Snap Neck: F while opponent is downed
>   En Garde Stance: Run left and then hold right, while continuing to hold left. Or vice versa.

Comment: What about with a game controller?